# Sometimes RxJava onError doesn’t catch Exception

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, okhttp

I have list of news. When user click one of the news, I show full news info. In that moment I send to backend request in header with alias of this news. Sometimes my app crashes. But this request have onError handler. I can't reproduce this error. But I see this error on Crashlytics.

I know there are Non ASCII symbols. Can't show all header. I have a lot of news and one of them can have Non ASCII symbols. I need to sure this error will be handle in onError and App won't crash.

Here is log error

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected char 0x430 at 12 in Params value: {"itemId":"акция"}
       at okhttp3.Headers$Companion.checkValue(Headers.java:434)
       at okhttp3.Headers$Companion.access$checkValue(Headers.java:346)
       at okhttp3.Headers$Builder.add(Headers.java:245)
       at okhttp3.Request$Builder.addHeader(Request.java:210)
       at com.example.NetworkModule.lambda$provideAuthOkHttpClient$1(NetworkModule.java:112)
       at com.example.-$$Lambda$NetworkModule$0kozbr2vzEMUs4EGFjGRxf09B6g.intercept(-.java)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:112)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:87)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:219)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:112)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:87)
       at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:194)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.java:138)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
```

Here is sample code.

```
mNetworkHelper.sendGrafanaMetrics()
                    .compose(RxUtil.applySchedulers())
                    .subscribe(response -> {
                    }, this::silentError);
```

This is part of the NetworkModule class. 112 line is .addHeader(PARAMS_HEADER, params);

```
@Module
public class NetworkModule implements Constants {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named("authClient")
    OkHttpClient provideAuthOkHttpClient(Context context, PreferencesHelper preferencesHelper, VeonApi veonApi, UserAgent userAgent, SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory, TrustManager[] trustManager) {
        Cache cache = new Cache(context.getCacheDir(), cacheSize);

        HttpLoggingInterceptor logInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor(message -> Log.d("myLogger", message))
                .setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);


        Interceptor authInterceptor = chain -> {
            Request original = chain.request();
            String params = userAgent.getJsonString();
            Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                    .addHeader(PARAMS_HEADER, params);
            String ticket = preferencesHelper.getTicket();

            if (addTicket && ticket != null) {
                Timber.v("--===adding ticket: %s", ticket);
                requestBuilder.addHeader(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER, ticket);
            } else {
                Timber.v("not adding ticket %s", ticket);
            }
            okhttp3.Response response = chain.proceed(requestBuilder.build());
            if (response.code() == 401) {
                Timber.v("Ticket Expired");
                if (preferencesHelper.rememberMe()) {
                    refreshTicket(veonApi, preferencesHelper);
                    ticket = preferencesHelper.getTicket();
                    if (ticket != null) {
                        requestBuilder.addHeader(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER, ticket);
                    }
                    response = chain.proceed(requestBuilder.build());
                } else {
                    return new okhttp3.Response.Builder()
                            .code(418)
                            .request(chain.request())
                            .protocol(response.protocol())
                            .message(context.getString(R.string.ticket_reload_required))
                            .body(ResponseBody.create(null,
                                    new Gson().toJson(new ResponseException(418, context.getString(R.string.ticket_reload_required)))))
                            .build();
                }
            }
            return response;
        };

        return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .protocols(Collections.singletonList(Protocol.HTTP_1_1))
                .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
                .addInterceptor(logInterceptor)
                .addInterceptor(authInterceptor)
                .cache(cache)
                .connectTimeout(TIMEOUT_SEC, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(TIMEOUT_SEC, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(TIMEOUT_SEC, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .hostnameVerifier((hostname, session) -> true)//todo should not be in prod
                .sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, (X509TrustManager) trustManager[0])//todo should not be in prod
                .build();
    }
}
```

sendGrafanaMetrics network request has only header data. This request need for statistic purpose. This is part of the header request. {"itemId":"новые данные"}. Sometimes in itemId I can recieve non ASCII symbols

Comment: What's happening here NetworkModule.java:112? Could you please provide some code regarding this line. How does sendGrafanaMetrics look like? My assumption would be, that some call is done eagerly and fails, before being wrapped into an Observable (e.g. reactive-type), therefore no onError. Example: Observable.just(myMethod());  void myMethod() { throw new RunTimeException(); }. In this example you would not get an onError, because myMethod is invoked before Observable#just. By invoking myMethod an Exception is thrown and propagated to the called (current Thread).

Comment: I updated question info. But I can’t reproduced this error myself. I see this error in Crashlytics. Also I can’t reproduced this error like you said. I tried reproduce this error like this. Before news load I turn off internet and catch UnknownHostException, then I tried send request with header with non ASCII symbols.

Comment: Are you sure, that the exception causes the app to crash? It is cleraly visible, that the stack-trace is from a thread in a threadpool. When a thread in a threadpool crashes, the app should not be stopped, because the UI-Eventloop should still be runing. The stacktrace shows, that a RealCall is being executed and the response (userAgent.getJsonString()) contains invalid characters. Therfore it should be reproducable, when userAgent.getJsonString contains non ASCII characters. Do you have any call like OkHttpClient#newCall(request).execute() anywhere? This would enqueue a Job in the Threadpool.

Comment: Yeah, I am sure, that the exception causes the app to crash because I see this crash in crashlytics. I have about 40000 users. about 6 users recieve this error

Answer (score 0):

Headers cannot contain non ASCII characters. Please refer to https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2896. Instead of you should try to decode the header value as base64.